# How to handle PUT request for a model with an extended user(onetoone field) relationship django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a profile model with a onetoone relationship with the django User model, I created an API endpoint which works fine for get and post request but when I try to do a put request to edit some part of the data, it gives me this error.

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

This is my Profile model

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

This is my Serializer class

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id' ,'username', 'first_name', 
                  'last_name', 'email',
                  'password')
        
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
        }


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A student serializer to return the student details
    """
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('uid', 'user', 'bio', 'location')
        # read_only_fields = ('user',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        
        user = instance.user

        instance.bio = validated_data.get('bio', instance.bio)
        instance.location = validated_data.get('location', instance.location)
        instance.save()

        user.username = user_data.get('username', user.username)
        user.first_name = user_data.get('first_name', user.first_name)
        user.last_name = user_data.get('last_name', user.last_name)

        user.save()

        return instance
```

And if there is obviously already a username in the response I want to perform a PUT request, and I don't want to change the username just some other data, it gives error { "user": { "username": [ "A user with that username already exists." ], "password": [ "This field is required." ] } }

Comment: how are you sending an request that you are sending?

Comment: I am using postman, so after I get the data for the required pk, I send the data using the postman key value pair.

Comment: already passed tried the data like this, user: {username: 'foo', first_name: 'bar' ...}?

Comment: if there is obviously already a username, and I don't want to change the username just some other data, it gives error {
    "user": {
        "username": [
            "A user with that username already exists."
        ],
        "password": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}

Comment: i think you can create another serializer for PUT method. This new serializer all fields will are optional